# redis takes 1 second to obtain lock, is it ok?

Tags: python, redis

Running on core i3 8Gb ssd etc, so is it ok or something wrong with configuration? No one else obtain this lock for sure. From my understanding memory operations should not be so slow.

```
import time
import redis

start = time.time()
with redis.StrictRedis().lock('mylock', timeout=1):
    end = time.time()

print(end - start) # 1.02099990845
```

Comment: That generally is *not* a reliable way to time things in Python.

Comment: Anyway it's visibly slow.

Comment: You're also measuring the time it takes to actually open the connection to Redis...

Comment: @Itamar Haber: Oh! Fine! Yes, it helps. Only first lock on StrictRedis object is time consuming!